# Bundler not seeing installed gem (with RVM)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

**The gem is in the bundle, but bundler can't see it.**

```
~/rails_projects/xxx $ rake db:migrate
  Could not find rdoc-4.2.0 in any of the sources
  Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

~/rails_projects/xxx $ bundle show rdoc
  /home/funkdified/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rdoc-4.2.0
```

*Addendum*

```
~/rails_projects/xxx $ bundle exec rake db:migrate
  Could not find rdoc-4.2.0 in any of the sources
  Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

bundle install
  Bundle complete! 26 Gemfile dependencies, 93 gems now installed.
  Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.

bundle show rdoc
  /home/funkdified/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rdoc-4.2.0

rvm gemdir
  /home/funkdified/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@xxx
```

**How can I make bundler see the bundle's gem?**

Comment: When you run `bundle install` in the that directory, does it install anything?

Comment: Try it with the --verbose flag

Comment: Ah, didn't notice you were using RVM. What does `ruby -v` return?

Comment: ruby 2.2.2p95 [x86_64-linux]

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute in the [context of bundler](http://bundler.io/v1.3/man/bundle-exec.1.html)

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

> This command executes the command, making all gems specified in the Gemfile(5) available to require in Ruby programs.

Comment: See my addition above. I don't think you need to run bundle exec in the context of a gemset. I have .ruby-gemset set and have created and used the corresponding gemset.

Answer (score 0):

TRY

```html
gem install bundler
```

There might be sometimes problem with the bundler gem